# Detecting rectangles using OpenCV 2.4.9

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

**WHAT I WANT TO DO :**

I want to detect rectangles in an image..

**WHAT I HAVE DONE SO FAR:**

```
    import cv2
    import numpy as np

    img_path = cv2.imread('/XXX/XXX.TIF',0)
    ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(img_path,127,255,0)
    contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, 1, 2)
    cnt = contours[0]
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    cv2.rectangle(img_path,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)

    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
    box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
    box = np.int0(box)
    im = cv2.drawContours(im,[box],0,(0,0,255),2)
```

**THE ERROR I AM GETTING :**

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'boxPoints'
```

Concerning this line of code:

```
    box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
```

**WHAT I THINK :** I beleive that it is caused by the version of OpenCV I am using (2.4.9).

Knowing that it is not possible for me now to pass to OpenCV 3.0, how can I make it work using openCV 2.9 and Python 2.7 ?

**EDIT & SOLUTION :**

So as answered by Surabhi Valma, this could be a solution :

```
Just add cv2.cv.BoxPoints(rect) instead of cv2.boxPoints(rect)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `cv2.cv.BoxPoints(rect)` instead of `cv2.boxPoints(rect)`

Comment: Thank you I have choosed this as a solution for this question.

Answer (score 1):

When I go thru [releases](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/releases) could not find 2.9. May be your version is 2.4.9. If you try with 3.x, it may work.

There was an [opencv-issue](http://answers.opencv.org/question/36643/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-boxpoints-in-249/) / [feature](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/1041/commits) already tracked to closure
This function is for sure available in 3.0.0-dev or above, Please try to upgrade and check.

Comment: Yes, my bad. It is 2.4.9 version. But as I said I cannot switch to the 3.X version now, I have to find a solution using OpenCV 2.4.9

Answer (score 1):

The most recent OpenCV 2 release is 2.4.13.2; there is no 2.9. Anyways, this method was never included in the `cv2` library with Python wrappers.
Your choices are to upgrade to OpenCV 3+ or fall back on the (deprecated) `cv` module (which is included with older versions of Python OpenCV wrappers) to access the C method directly:

```
rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
box = np.int0(cv2.cv.BoxPoints(rect))
cv2.drawContours(im,[box],0,(0,0,255),2)
```

Comment: `rect` and `box` lines are working but the third line is giving this error:

`TypeError: contours is not a numerical tuple `

Comment: Try `box = np.int0(cv2.cv.BoxPoints(rect))`. You may or may not need the `[]` around `box`...I'm not sure as I don't have 2.4 installed on my system so I can't troubleshoot it. Can you print out the values of `box`? What do they look like?

Comment: `box
Out[96]: 
array([[1024,  958],
       [1024,  958],
       [1024,  958],
       [1024,  958]])`

Comment: Actually the new line of code `box = np.int0(cv2.cv.BoxPoints(rect))` works there is no message error, but no image is displayed ! I beleive that `cv2.drawContours` line is the line that shows the rectangles on the image right ?

Comment: No, it doesn't display it, it modifies the image in place by drawing the contours onto the image. You'll need to use `cv2.imshow('Window Name', im)` and `cv2.waitKey(0)` as usual afterwards to view it.

Comment: Apparently I have problems with this OpenCV release I have installed !

`error: /home/vagrant/pisi/tmp/opencv-2.4.9-5/work/opencv-2.4.9/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:501: error: (-2) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function cvShowImage`

Comment: Please search Stack for related errors, that is a very common message. Follow the instructions in the message. If you installed with `pip` (i.e. `pip opencv-python` then you won't have GUI support. Otherwise you probably just need to rebuild (with the packages it says in the message). If you don't feel like doing that now and just want to see your result, you can write the image with `cv2.imwrite('filename.png',im)` and browse and open the image.